# Why does a python "in" statement evaluate this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

Sorry, I couldn't think of a more descriptive title. This isn't super important, but rather a weird quirk in python 3.8 (at least) that I found, and I figured I can't be the only one who's noticed this, and there's probably a reasonable explanation:

```py
>>> 'foo' in 'foobar' == True
False
```

It works the other way too:

```py
>>> True == 'foo' in 'foobar'
False
```

However, logically I would think this should be True, as

```py
>>> 'foo' in 'foobar'
True
>>> True == True
True
```

I'm assuming it's some kind of order of operations error, but when I try to group it I get

```py
>>> ('foo' in 'foobar') == True
True
>>> 'foo' in ('foobar' == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

I'm mostly just really curious at this point, if someone could explain this that'd be great!

Answer (score 6):

Because of [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) the expression is equivalent to:

```
('foo' in 'foobar') and ('foobar' == True)
```

Since `'foobar' == True` is `False`, the whole expression is `False`.

Comment: Looks exactly right. You can also try evaluating `'foo' in 'foobar' in 'foobarbaz'` (`True`), while adding parentheses either way causes a type error.